# Make a $match query in $project

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a topic with a field *subscribers*. This field is an array and contains all the subscriber ids.

When a user makes a query to get all the topics, I want to put a flag for each topic that specified if the user already subscribes to the topic or not.

```
topic.aggregate([
        {"$match" : { "subscribers" :  new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myUserId) }},
])
```

If I exec this query I get only the topic the user subscribes to but I need to get all the topics  !!

```
topic.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    "_id":1,
    "title":1,
    "subscribe":{ "subscribers" : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myUserId) }
  }
]}
```

And this aggregation doesn't work. How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.topic.aggregate([
    { $project : 
      { 
        "_id" : 1, 
        "title" : 1, 
        "subscribed" : { $cond : [ { $setIsSubset : [ [new ObjectId(myUserId)], "$subscribers"] }, true, false ] } 
      } 
    }
])
```